# Non-collective MySQL WHERE OR clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

'Non-collective' my not be the correct term for this so please suggest a better description and I shall amend :)

Basically, I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT 
  image_id, image_col1, image_col2
FROM
  images 
WHERE (
    (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) 
    OR
    (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) 
    OR
    (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0)
  )
```

This returns four rows:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| image_id | image_col1 | image_col2 |
+----------+------------+------------+
|         1|           2|           3|
+----------+------------+------------+
|         2|           2|           3|
+----------+------------+------------+
|         3|           2|           0|
+----------+------------+------------+
|         4|           1|           0|
+----------+------------+------------+
```

What I want it to do is ignore the other parts of the WHERE if one of the conditions finds some rows, i.e. in this example, I only want the first two rows, because they matched the first condition, and if none matched that condition, I'd only want the third row, as that matched the second condition.

Currently, I am running 3 queries, one for each condition, and then using the first one that isn't an empty result, but want to try and do it in one query.

I basically don't want it to combine the conditions to find rows that match any of them, I want it to stop once a condition returns something.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having different rule to apply in cascade is not an easy feat.
The possibility to use `CTE` will help the readability, at least.

```
SELECT i.image_id, i.image_col1, i.image_col2
FROM   (SELECT image_id, image_col1, image_col2
             , CASE WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) THEN 1
                    WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 2
                    WHEN (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 3 
                    ELSE 0 
               END Cond
        FROM   images) i
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(CASE 
                                WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) 
                                  THEN 1
                                WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) 
                                  THEN 2
                                WHEN (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0) 
                                  THEN 3 
                                ELSE 0 
                              END) Cond
                   FROM   images) a ON i.Cond = a.Cond
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57319/3)

The field `Cond` in the two subqueries return which rule apply to the row, the rule must be mutually exclusive.
The second subquery apply the same rules to get the first rule that apply to the dataset, that's why the rules are numbered and not simply checked.

It's possible to do the same thing without the `JOIN` checking the condition in the `WHERE`

```
SELECT image_id, image_col1, image_col2
FROM   images
WHERE  CASE WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) THEN 1
            WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 2
            WHEN (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 
       END
       = 
       (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) THEN 1
                        WHEN (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 2
                        WHEN (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0) THEN 3 
                        ELSE 0 
                   END) Cond
        FROM   images)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57319/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT image_id, image_col1, image_col2, 
       case when (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 3) then 1 else 0 
       case when (image_col1 = 2 AND image_col2 = 0) then 1 else 0
       case when (image_col1 = 1 AND image_col2 = 0) then 1 else 0
     END as img 
     FROM images
```